# iOS - auto layout rotation not working as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

I have app with enabled rotation for iPad (iPhone version is rotation-free). In my design, within storyboard, I have this hierarchy: `UIView - UIScrollView - UIView`. All "views" are set to have full width of the screen. Second `UIView` has class set to `MyView`, which is a class with an external `xib` file. Storyboard and xib are both created in a portrait mode.

Now for the problem.

- If I run the app in the landscape mode, all is loaded OK. If I rotate
  app after that, all is OK.
- If I run the app in the portrait mode, the design "breaks". The entire content is thiner (so there is about 100+ px gap between the end of `MyView` and the end of the screen). If I rotate app, the design remains broken but correctly "enlarged". The gap is still of the same size. During the first launch, I got the following error in debugger:

  ```
  Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
  Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
  Try this: 
      (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
      (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
  (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
   (
  "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1545b7800 h=-&- v=-&- UIView:0x1546a8cb0.width == ScrollableContentView:0x154575da0.width - 232>",
  "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15458dd80 H:[UIActivityIndicatorView:0x1546afa60]-(370)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1546ab840 )>",
  "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15458ddd0 H:|-(361)-[UIActivityIndicatorView:0x1546afa60]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1546ab840 )>",
  "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1546c7080 H:[UIView:0x1546ab840]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1546a8cb0 )>",
  "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1546c7120 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x1546ab840]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1546a8cb0 )>",
  "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x154579710 H:|-(0)-[ScrollableContentView:0x154575da0]   (Names: '|':UIScrollView:0x15504c000 )>",
  "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x154686ef0 UIScrollView:0x15504c000.centerX == ScrollableContentView:0x154575da0.centerX>",
  "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x154697cc0 H:[UIScrollView:0x15504c000]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x154547b80 )>",
  "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x154697d10 H:|-(0)-[UIScrollView:0x15504c000]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x154547b80 )>",
  "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15463b8c0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x154547b80(768)]>"
  )

   Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
  ```

No matter what I do, I am unable to remove this problem. Even If I deleted almost every constraint I have still the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should look if you don't have any auto layout warnings in your storyboard or xib file (yellow/red dot beside your controller name in document outline).

If you don't have any, do you set your constraints when adding your xib view ?

Have you think about `content hugging priority` or `content compression resistance priority` ?

Comment: is it possible for you to extract your view, xib, and layout setup code and put all that on a github ? We could easily look at it like that. Also is it correct that you add your xib programmatically ? Do you set auto layout constraint while doing it ?

Comment: I am sorry, but the code/design is internal and I cannot "release" it until app is in store. I am not adding xib manually, but via class setting in property window.

Comment: "is it correct that you add your xib programmatically ? Do you set auto layout constraint while doing it ?"

Comment: If this would be broken, I suspect, that it wont be working at all (meaning it will be broken even from the landscape "start")

Comment: I'd recommend you to check all constraints linked to the objects listed in your debug log. Without any other informations I don't think I can help. Hope you'll find